# Is it possible to get render metrics (time) from ag-grid-react?

Tags: newrelic, ag-grid-react

I'm looking for a way to get render metrics from ag-grid(-react) and publish them to a New Relic dashboard. Currently I'm using New Relic Browser SPA API to create and end an interaction. The point is that I'm not able to find the correct "place" (methods/callback/events) where doing it.

At first I instrumented my component's `componentWillUpdate` and `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle methods but a colleague told me it would not work because ag-grid renders "disconnected" from React. ag-grid offers `onRowDataChanged` event but I'm not sure if this method is called before the rendering starts of after it ends. And, anyway, I would need a pair of methods where to start New Relic's interaction and end it.

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks!